# MongoDB search nested objects in an array

Tags: laravel, mongodb, nosql

I am using MongoDB to store all the events in my Eventbrite clone. So I have a collection called events then the objects in this collection consists of their name and and array of users that have rsvp to the event. I can query for any events that the current user has created but unable to figure out how to query both events the user has created and rsvp to.

Here is the compiled query that I am using to try to get all the users events.

```
events.find({"$and":[{"user_id":"5d335704802df000076bad97"},{"user_id":{"$ne":null}}],"$or":[{"checkins.user_id":"5d335704802df000076bad97"}]},{"typeMap":{"root":"array","document":"array"}})
```

I am using the Laravel MongoDB plugin to query my data in php it looks like this

```
$user->events()->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user){
            return $query->where('checkins.user_id',new ObjectID($user->id));
        })->get()
```

The event object looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "user_id": "1"
    "rsvp": [
        {"user_id": "12"}
    ]
}
```

An user can rsvp to other event that are not their own.

Answer (score 0):

you need an `$or` filter and `$elemMatch` to get events that belong to a given user or events they've rsvp'd to.

```java
db.events.find({
    "$or": [
        {
            "user_id": "5d33e732e1ea9d0d6834ef3d"
        },
        {
            "rsvp": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "user_id": "5d33e732e1ea9d0d6834ef3d"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

unfortunately i can't help you with laravel version of the query. in case it helps, below is the c# code that generated the above mongo query.

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class user : Entity
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        public class Event : Entity
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string user_id { get; set; }
            public rsvp[] rsvp { get; set; }
        }

        public class rsvp
        {
            public string user_id { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var mike = new user { name = "mike" };
            var dave = new user { name = "dave" };
            mike.Save();
            dave.Save();

            (new[] {
                new Event
                {
                    name = "mike's event",
                    user_id = mike.ID,
                    rsvp = new[]
                    {
                        new rsvp { user_id = dave.ID }
                    }
                },
                new Event
                {
                    name = "dave's event",
                    user_id = dave.ID,
                    rsvp = new[]
                    {
                        new rsvp { user_id = mike.ID }
                    }
                }
            }).Save();

            var result = DB.Find<Event>()
                           .Many(e =>
                                 e.user_id == mike.ID ||
                                 e.rsvp.Any(r => r.user_id == mike.ID));
        }
    }
}
```